# How to get an object from via its association with an ActiveRecord query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Using Rails 5.0:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cart, {:optional => true}
end

class Phone < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cart_items
end

class CartItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cart, {:optional => true} #has cart_id as column 
  belongs_to :phone, {:optional => true} #has phone_id as column
end

class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user
  has_many :cart_items
end
```

My app works as follows. There are users (`User`), that have carts (`Cart`), and in those carts have cart items (`CartItem`). In each of those cart items there is information regarding the cart including what phones are purchased (`Phone`).

I am currently using an `.each` loop to loop through `user.cart.cart_items`, if it returns a cart item has `params[:phone_id]`, then it would update it and break from the loop.

```
user_items = @user.cart.cart_items
if user_items.any?{|x| x.phone_id == params[:phone_id].to_i}

  user_items.each do |x|
  if x.phone_id == params[:phone_id].to_i
    x.update_attributes(:quantity_sold => params[:quantity].to_i)
    break
  end
  end
```

end

Although it works, I was wondering whether there was a way to use a database query to find all associated phones associated with the user_items (`@user.cart.cart_items`). Note: `@user` is just the current user logged in.

I tried using `@user.cart.cart_items.where(:phone_id => 1)`, and it worked, but when trying to retrieve the phone from there via the query `@user.cart.cart_items.where(:phone_id => 1).phone`, it returned the error `undefined method 'phone' for #<CartItem::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fa38a461128>`.

I checked to see whether my associations were set up correctly via (`cart_item.phones`, and `phone.cart_items`, and they worked fine (`cart_item` = instance of `CartItem` and `phone` = instance of `Phone`).

Is there a way I can use a database query from an association to find all user cart items (`@user.cart.cart_items`) that have a phone id of x (params)? Note: I need the actual object, so I can look through fields of the phone (i.e.: `@user.cart.cart_items.phone.brand_name`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you related CartItems:

```
user_items_with_matching_phone = @user.cart.cart_items.where(phone_id: x)
```

To get the first item's phone:

```
user_items_with_matching_phone.first.phone
```

To update the first item (basically what you did in the each loop):

```
user_items_with_matching_phone.first.update_attributes(quantity_sold: params[:quantity].to_i)
```

However, you can not do `user_items_with_matching_phone.phone` because `user_items_with_matching_phone` is more similar to an array than a single object. You can get the length if by `user_items_with_matching_phone.size`

Comment: Thanks... just curious which you would recommend for an app. The `.each` method that iterates on an existing SQL query or a separate database query (essentially the answer you gave)?

Comment: SQL query should be more efficient in most cases. In this problem, `where(phone_id: x)` is far more efficient than finding a matching record using each loop.